# Color line numbers RED with SUDOEDIT

Tags: vimrc, sudo

I want to have a visual feedback when editing files with root privileges.

I had in my `.vimrc` this config

```
" Color line numbers RED with root 
if $USER == 'root' 
    highlight LineNr ctermfg=red 
else 
    highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey 
endif
```

and it works fine as long as I copy (or symlink) this to `/root/.vimrc` and edit files with `sudo vim path_to_file`

I think (correct my if I'm wrong) that it is best practice to use `sudoedit` (why?) and not use the symlink approach.

**The problem**

When using `sudoedit` I don't know how to check if it. The `$USER` variable doesn't change to `root`. So my line numbers don't show up in red.

**The question**

How can I know from `.vimrc` if `sudoedit` is being used?

Comment: Yes, `sudoedit` is a good idea: it makes a copy, which you edit as your normal user, and then moves that edited copy back to the original file. There are several good reasons to do this, but as you point out it may not be detectable. You could try to find out if the PPID corresponds to `sudoedit` or `sudo -e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @d-ben-knoble I've found a workaround: check if parent PID's name equals `sudoedit`.

```
" Color line numbers RED with root
let ppid=systemlist("awk '{print $4}' /proc/" . getpid() . "/stat")[0]
let ppname=systemlist("ps -p " . ppid . " -o comm=")[0]

if $USER == 'root' || ppname == 'sudoedit'
    highlight LineNr ctermfg=red
else
    highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey
endif
```